# Why do we need clone the grad_output and assign it to grad_input when defining a ReLU autograd function?

Tags: pytorch, backpropagation, autograd

I'm walking through the autograd part of pytorch tutorials. I have two questions:

1. Why do we need clone the `grad_output` and assign it to `grad_input` other than simple assignment during backpropagation?
2. What's the purpose of `grad_input[input < 0] = 0`? Does it mean we don't update the gradient when input less than zero?

Here's the code:

```py
class MyReLU(torch.autograd.Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, input):
        """
        In the forward pass we receive a Tensor containing the input and return
        a Tensor containing the output. ctx is a context object that can be used
        to stash information for backward computation. You can cache arbitrary
        objects for use in the backward pass using the ctx.save_for_backward method.
        """
        ctx.save_for_backward(input)
        return input.clamp(min=0)

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        """
        In the backward pass we receive a Tensor containing the gradient of the loss
        with respect to the output, and we need to compute the gradient of the loss
        with respect to the input.
        """
        input, = ctx.saved_tensors
        grad_input = grad_output.clone()
        grad_input[input < 0] = 0
        return grad_input
```

Link here:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/pytorch_with_examples.html#pytorch-defining-new-autograd-functions

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do we need clone the grad_output and assign it to grad_input other than simple assignment during backpropagation?

`tensor.clone()` creates a copy of tensor that imitates the original tensor's `requires_grad` field. `clone` is a way to copy the tensor while still keeping the copy as a part of the computation graph it came from.

So, `grad_input` is part of the same computation graph as `grad_output` and if we compute the gradient for `grad_output`, then the same will be done for `grad_input`.

Since we make changes in `grad_input`, we clone it first.

> What's the purpose of 'grad_input[input < 0] = 0'? Does it mean we don't update the gradient when input less than zero?

This is done as per ReLU function's definition. The ReLU function is `f(x)=max(0,x)`. It means if `x<=0` then `f(x)=0`, else `f(x)=x`. In the first case, when `x<0`, the derivative of `f(x)` with respect to `x` is `f'(x)=0`. So, we perform `grad_input[input < 0] = 0`. In the second case, it is `f'(x)=1`, so we simply pass the `grad_output` to `grad_input` (works like an open gate).

Comment: Thanks for your answer,you really helped me a lot!

Comment: What would be the reason to not just do `return grad_output.clamp(min=0)` or  `return F.relu(grad_output)`? Is the clone method more efficient?